# Menu WordPress get nav menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following html structure:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-fw">
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="coach.html">coach</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="speaker.html">speaker</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="training.html">training</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="online-content.html">online content</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="coming-soon.html">coming soon</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="index.html">corporate</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

I would like to use wp_get_nav_menu_bar to display the items of my WordPress menu.

For now use this and it's a list with my items

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Top' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to use get nav menu item to have the same html structure

Comment: is it bootstrap dom style?

Comment: yes i use bootstrap